# Initialize class pointer object with reference to another class object

Tags: c++

I know this is a general question in C++, and my knowledge of it is all that needs to be improved in order to understand it.

But my problem is not knowing how to ask the question, so I'm having trouble googling it.

I want to initialize a pointer object of a class with a reference to a different class' object.

Assume we have two classes: One, Two.

I wanna do the following:

```
Two objOfTwo = Two(2):
One* objPointer[2] = { &objOfTwo, &objOfTwo };
```

The code is merely an example of what I want to do, so ignore the fact it's the same object for both indexes.

My question is how do I go about making sure this class accepts this type of initialization? A special constructor?

Thank you.

Comment: If the types are correct, the compiler will accept this type of initialization.  No special constructor needed.

Comment: You need Compile Time Type Checking or the concepts in C++20.

Comment: `I want to initialize a pointer object of a class with a reference to a different class' object.` are you talking about a polymorphic type?

Comment: This can only work if `Two` is a subclass of `One`. Can you give more details of the problem you're trying to solve. No, not about initializing pointers, like this, but the problem to which you believe the solution involves initializing a pointer like this?

Comment: Sam's answer seems to be the correct answer. This part of the code was given to me. I'm a student and I'm trying to make an assignment. I assume they wanted us to use inheritance and that was their way of forcing us to use it. @Sam_Varshavchik thank you.